# Map flaggable enum to array

Tags: c#, enums, bit-manipulation

I have a flaggable enum from a database that I want to convert to an enum array of a 3rd party.

For that, I'm using the following code:

```
    private TheirEnum[] GetTheirEnums(MyEnum? ourEnums)
    {
        List<TheirEnum> result = new List<TheirEnum>();
        if (ourEnums != null)
        {
            if (ourEnums.Value.HasFlag(MyEnum.Geothermal))
            {
                result.Add(TheirEnum.GEOTHERMAL);
            }

            if (ourEnums.Value.HasFlag(MyEnum.SolarHeating))
            {
                result.Add(TheirEnum.SOLAR_HEATING);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            result.Add(TheirEnum.NO_INFORMATION);
        }

        return result.ToArray();
    }
```

However, as there are more than 50 entries in that enum list, I assume this would get very messy and ugly. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple solution would be to create `OurEnum` based on `TheirEnum`, then a simple cast would do the trick.

here is an example:

```
    [Flags]
    public enum TheirEnum
    {
        GEOTHERMAL=1,
        SOLAR_HEATING=2,
        NO_INFORMATION=4
    }


    [Flags]
    public enum OurEnum
    {
        Geothermal=TheirEnum.GEOTHERMAL,
        SolarHeating=TheirEnum.SOLAR_HEATING,
        NoInformation=TheirEnum.NO_INFORMATION
    }
```

or even you can just use the values:

```
    [Flags]
    public enum OurEnum
    {
        Geothermal=1,
        SolarHeating=2,
        NoInformation=4
    }
```

then a simple cast would convert it:

```
        var ourValue = OurEnum.Geothermal | OurEnum.NoInformation;
        var theirValue = (TheirEnum) ourValue;
```

at last we can simply create an array based on flagged enums in `theirValue` :

```
        var values=Enum.GetValues(typeof(TheirEnum));
        var array= (from TheirEnum v in values where theirValue.HasFlag(v) select v).ToArray();
```